# Hadoop Map Reduce CustomRecordReader

Tags: java, hadoop

I followed [this](http://bigdatacircus.com/2012/08/01/wordcount-with-custom-record-reader-of-textinputformat/) guide to create a custom inputsplit for hadoop. Now I have an exception each time on this:

```
FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
```

I imported this 2:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
```

but I do not understand why give me exception. `FileSplit` extends the `InputSplit`, so why exceptions?

Comment: What exception do you get sir?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit cannot be cast to

Comment: @Pascal NoPascensor: Cast to...?

Comment: @Pascal NoPascensor: I'm *guessing* it says "cast to `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
```

and not

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
```

Or, at the least, you seem to be mixing the use of these two *different* classes ([`o.a.h.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileSplit.html) vs [`o.a.h.mapred.FileSplit`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileSplit.html)). Read your exception message carefully.

Comment: @Pascal NoPascensor: Good luck. It's sort of a jumbled mess from the old API (`o.a.h.mapred`) to the new API (`o.a.h.mapreduce`).